# Twilio costs, and displaying alternative name as phone number

Tags: php, twilio

I am sending sms using Twilio, and it says there that the pricing for the SMS costs $0.02 when sending texts to the Philippines. I looked at my account and noticed that it charged $0.20.

Also, how can I display "Gian" as the sender instead of a random Twilio number when sending sms because I am receiving sms as +123178232(whatever) and I would like this to be changed to my name.. Can anyone who has done this before or who has any idea on how to to this help me?

Comment: Twilio pricing is not a programming issue. You'll have to take that up with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If there has been a billing mistake, I'd advise you to take that up with our help team by emailing help@twilio.com and including your Account SID.

In order to send SMS messages using an alphanumeric sender ID you need to check that the country you are sending messages to [supports alphanumeric sender IDs](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-countries-does-twilio-support-alphanumeric-sender-id) (the Philippines does) and then use the text you want to send instead of your Twilio number as the `from` parameter in your REST API call. Like so:

```
// require the Twilio helper library
require "Services/Twilio.php";

// set your AccountSid and AuthToken from www.twilio.com/user/account
$AccountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$AuthToken = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";

$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

// send the message using your name instead of a number as the from parameter
$sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage("Gian", $toNumber, "Your message");
```

Note that if you send using an alphanumeric sender ID then people who receive those SMS messages will not be able to reply. See all the other details about sender IDs here: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-is-alphanumeric-sender-id-and-how-do-i-get-started

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have already sent an email to the help@twilio.But now I have a new problem,can you help me how I can send to multilple numbers? I have a <select multiple> called cmbCus in my form and I am posting the values to another php file. 

I currently have this:
`code` $customers = $_POST['cmbCus'];

foreach($customers as $x) {          $queryCustomerNumber = mysql_query("select DISTINCT mobile_num from cliente where FULL_NAME='$x'", $connection);
$queryResult2= mysql_fetch_assoc($queryCustomerNumber);         $customerNum=$queryResult2['MOBILE_NUM'];}`code`

Comment: Hey Gian, it's probably easier if you open a new SO question than ask a new one in the comments of my answer. If you tag it "Twilio" it will come up in my feed. Did the help with the alphanumeric sender ID work at all?

Comment: yes. I will mark this as answer. I will now post a new question :)

Comment: @GianMarcoTe Hey...was the Twilio number you bought on the site a Philippine number? My alph numeric is changed to another number.

Comment: Hey @Visionwriter, that sounds like something you should contact Twilio support with. Send them an email at help@twilio.com and they will be able to sort you out.

Comment: Yeah, they're just taking too damn long to respond and I need to get this done.

Comment: Can you drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com with your ticket number and I'll see if I can find out what's going on.

Comment: Ah, initially sent the email to the wrong address. Just sent it to the one you mentioned. Awaiting a response.

Comment: Cool, let me know if you don't hear soon.

Comment: Hey @philnash , it was taken care of. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for letting me know!